# Can not save file using the below python code. AttributeError: 'Array' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, image-processing

Can not save the file using the below python code. AttributeError: 'Array' object has no attribute 'save'. Can anyone help how to save file? I guess the last line of the code has some issue.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import imageio
    import scipy.ndimage
    import os import cv2 

    DATADIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
    path_to_photos = os.path.join(DATADIR, 'Dataset\CUHK_training_photo\photo') path_to_sketch_photos = os.path.join(DATADIR, 'Dataset\Sketches') 

    img_list = os.listdir(path_to_photos) 

    def dodge(front,back):
        result=front*255/(255-back)
        result[result>255]=255
        result[back==255]=255
        return result.astype('uint8') 

    def grayscale(rgb):
        return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]) 

    for file in img_list: 

        s = imageio.imread(path_to_photos + '\\' + file)
        g=grayscale(s) = 255-g 

        b = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(i,sigma=10)
        r= dodge(b,g) 

        r.save(path_to_sketch_photos + '\\' + file, 'JPEG') # Generate ERROR
```

[image: image of my code]

Comment: Sorry, I assume you are trying to save the ndarray as a binary file?

Comment: In the future, please don't post your code as a screen capture. Instead, copy and paste the code text. Indent everything by 4 space characters to get it to look like code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you might want to try

```
np.save(path_to_sketch_photos + "\\" + file +".JPEG",r)
```

or use the os module

```
from os import path, extsep
import numpy as np

filename = path.join(path_to_sketch_photos, file + extsep + "JPEG")
np.save(filename, r)
```

Comment: mind providing more detail on your error? Is it the same error?

Comment: nope...here is the error...**mainFile.py:14: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  result=front*255/(255-back)
mainFile.py:14: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  result=front*255/(255-back)
mainFile.py:15: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  result[result>255]=255**

Comment: Probably during the calculations 255-back became 0, giving you the divide by zero. Sorry I can't help to debug without the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

`r.save` won't work, because `r` is an array, and arrays don't have a `save` method.

[wontleave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3381961/wontleave) is correct when they say that what you want is something like:

```
filename = "blah.np"
np.save(filename, r)
```

The error `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide result=front*255/(255-back)` indicates that you divided something by zero.

Look at the line `result=front*255/(255-back)`. What if `back == 255`?

```
255-back        becomes   255-255 == 0
255/(255-back)  becomes   255/0
```